# sugarcrm list view column showing count

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to show a column in list view in opportunities,where the column contains Activity count  for each opportunity
Hw can this be achieved,is  there any logichok which supports that ?

Answer (score -1):

You could do a Sugar Logic rollup for this:

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/02/13/howto-use-sugar-logic-rollups/